# How to find out the version of savon(SOAP client for Ruby) installed?

Tags: ruby, version, savon

Please suggest the command to find out the version of savon already installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a list of all your gems and their version number use:

```
gem list
```

If you use bundler, then you can get the version from:

```
bundle show [gemname]
```

If you use RVM:

```
[gemname] --version
```

Or list all your gems:

```
rvm gemset list
```